# What does LExIM stand for?

Tags: extension, developer

I've heard a few developers refer to `LExIM`. What on earth is it?

(Other than "Reading" in Albanian or an on-line learning company?)

Answer (score 6):

LExIM is the new overall release and extension strategy:

## LEAP BY EXTENSION. ITERATE BY MONTH.

> It basically means that:
>
> - CiviCRM development will now happen mostly through extensions, enabling the users to individually turn these new features on or off by enabling these new extensions
> - Releases are going to be published on a predictable monthly schedule, facilitating planning and execution of regular updates by CiviCRM service providers (from [here](https://www.cividesk.com/blog/post/lexim-and-what-it-means-you))

See also: [blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/releases-we-are-what-we-repeatedly-do) and [wiki article](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/LExIM+and+the+Monthly+release+cycle).